# Using Twisted on a server without installation privileges?

Tags: python, installation, twisted

I have a server that I'd like to use to maintain persistent connections with a set of devices, just so that they can pass simple messages back and forth. It's a trivial task, but selecting a server-side platform has been suprrisingly difficult (especially since I have no administrative privileges - it's a dedicated commercial server).

My best idea so far is to write a TCP server in Python. The Twisted platform seems suitable for the task, and has a lot of good reviews. However, my server has Python 2.7 but not Twisted, and the admins have been reluctant to install it for me.

Is there any way that I can just upload a Twisted package to the server and reference it in my libraries without installing it as a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "installing it as a framework".  If you are using an OS X server hosting environment, then maybe you're talking about Framework with a Capital F.  However, OS X server hosting isn't a very common environment so I'm guessing that's not it.

If you just want to know how to install a Python library in your home directory, then the general answer is:

```
$ python setup.py install --user
```

This Just Works™ on Python 2.7 (assuming the package uses distutils, which Twisted does, and you unpack the source .tar.gz and change your working directory to the directory that is the root of the contents of that .tar.gz), so you should be done after that.

Comment: (OSX? No, it's not OSX at all...? It's RedHat running bash.)

Thanks for the comment. I tried that and it failed, but then I learned that my domain was installed on a server running Python 2.2.something (circa 2006!)... the admins are moving my stuff to a box with Python 2.7, and I'll try it there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use virtualenv to create your private Python libraries installation.